# Iterating in incresing steps

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over  a list of elements in increasing steps(assuming that We do not know the length of the list). 
To be specific: on first iteration process 2^1 elements, on 2nd step process 2^2. So every ith round will be processing 2**i elements.

I managed to get it working:

```
tmp = iter(A)
i = 0
no_inserted = 0 
while True:
for elm in tmp:
    print i,elm
    no_inserted = no_inserted + 1
    if no_inserted == 2**i:
        i = i +1
        print "New round"
else:
    break
```

But somehow it does not look right. Is there any better way to do it in python ?

Comment: This question is more suited towards CodeReview, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you have example input list `A` and output?

Comment: I was not aware there there is something called as codereview. I will keep that in my mind. Thanks

Comment: @Marcin We are not assuming anything about input.They are just a list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this what you want?

```
def iter_incr(l, base):
    limit = base
    while limit <= len(l) + (base-1):
        yield l[:limit]
        limit += base


tmp = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for res in iter_incr(tmp, 2):
    print(res)

# Results:
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood what you wanted. The below will probably makes more sense then.

```
def gen_slice(xs, low=0, step=1, high=None):
    """
    >>> xs = gen_slice(range(1, 10), 1)
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    StopIteration

    To start with an empty slice set the low to 0
    >>> xs = gen_slice(range(1, 10), 0)
    >>> list(next(xs))
    []

    To stop on part of the iterable rather than use all elements
    >>> xs = gen_slice(range(1, 10), 1, high=3)
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    StopIteration

    You could use the step to for bigger strides
    >>> xs = gen_slice(range(1, 10), low=0, step=2, high=4)
    >>> list(next(xs))
    []
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2]
    >>> list(next(xs))
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

    """
    high = high or len(xs)
    while True:
        yield itertools.islice(xs, 0, low)
        if low == high:
            break
        low += step
```

Comment: I guess I was not very specific: What i was trying to accomplish was to to call a function after having processed 2^i elements. In this case i am just going to get elements in which are placed at 2^ith place. Thanks for the reply